# удалить первый символ в строке

Tags: c++

В заданной с клавиатуры строке удалить первый символ без erase

Answer (score 2):

и вывести на консоль:

```
cin.ignore() >> cout.rdbuf();
```

Comment: Снимаю шляпу! :)

Comment: @Harry, я это делал много раз при ваших ответах и замечаниях, потому приятно слышать от вас. В данном случаи  какая то способность не нужна  _ всего лишь информация из стандартной библиотеки, где так много полезного, что если  ознакомиться, то  многие написанных нами кодов окажутся  лишними.

Comment: Просто ознакомиться мало, надо еще суметь эти знания использовать вот так, как у вас - емко и красиво...